# Elasticsearch search yields no results, analyzers might be the issue

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, analyzer

Elasticsearch version: **1.6.0**

I've been using elasticsearch for the last months (just started) and now I'm running into problems with it. Here is some info about my database:

The index I'm using uses the default dynamic mapping (eg: I haven't tinkered with its mapping). My objects should be schema-free.  Also the index uses the default analyzer (I haven't touched that either) so `index/_settings` looks like this:

```
{
    "default": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1441808338958",
                "uuid": "34Yn1_ixSqOzp9UotOE_4g",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "version": {
                    "created": "1060099"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the issue I'm having**: on some field values the search does not work as expected (I concluded it's because of the analyzer). Example: the field `email` has the value `user@example.com`; `{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"user.email":"user@example.com"}}]}}` won't work, but having the term value as just "user" works (because it somehow tokenizes it, and there is no token with the full email address).

**Here's what I want**: I want both **wildcard** text searches (finding a bad word in a comment's text) AND **strict** searches (like on email for example) on any field, then I'll be using `bool` and `should` with either `term` or `wildcard`.

The problem is I just can't tell him "ok, on this field you should use the X analyzer" because all my fields are dynamic.

**What I've tried**: On the index's settings I PUT-ed this: `{"analysis":{"analyzer":{"default":{"type":"keyword"}}}}`; doesnt' work: nothing changed (I also didn't forget to close the index before doing so and open it).

Is this issue even related to analyzers ?

Comment: if you change the [analyzer setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html#reindex)  you would need to reindex the documents .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Ryan Huynh I've solved my issue:

Use **dynamic mappings**; create the index like so:

```
PUT /index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_template": {
            "mapping": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This query won't work

> {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"user.email":"user@example.com"}}]}}

Term is exact match, meaning whatever your value for that field ("**user@example.com**" in your case) must match whatever **tokens** ES has for that field.

When you don't assign any analyzer for that field, ES will assume you are using standard analyzer for that field. When this "user@example.com" indexed, it will be tokenized into ("user","example","com").

To solve your problem you have to tell ES to "not_analyzed" the email field in your index's mapping.

Comment: I need to do this for all my fields (which are dynamic). So I guess I have to make a dynamic mapping